# Property of HTML Meta - Tags throw a warning in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, validation, xhtml

I have some meta tags for facebook and google in my HTML page, but eclipse shows a warning on the "property" and "itemprop". I tried different doctypes but it does not validate. Is there a way of getting rid of the warnings without disabling the validation for the HTML documents?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

    <head>

        <!-- Facebook meta tags -->
        <meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />  
        <meta property="og:description" content="My Description" />  

         <!-- Meta tags for google. -->
        <meta itemprop="name" content="My Title"/>
        <meta itemprop="description" content="My Description"/>

    </head>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Validation

Check Ignore specified attribute names in validation and add "property, itemprop" to the text field bellow.